# Access last N documents of Google Firestore collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access last N documents from google firestore collection. The key for documents are timestamp in ISO format. The collection first needs to be sorted on timestamp keys and the last N documents updated are to be retrieved. This operation has to be realtime and fast.

```
events(collection) =>
documents as below:
2019-01-07T08:21:18.600Z => {
  symbolname: '10900CE',
  price: '10825.0',
  timestamp: '2019-01-07T13:51:18Z',
  quantity: '2.0',
  side: 'SELL' }
2019-01-07T08:21:28.614Z => { 
  symbolname: '10800PE',
  price: '10825.0',
  timestamp: '2019-01-07T13:51:28Z',
  quantity: '2.0',
  side: 'BUY' }
2019-01-07T09:45:24.783Z => { side: 'SELL',
  symbolname: '10800PE',
  price: '10805.0',
  timestamp: '2019-01-07T15:15:24Z',
  quantity: '2.0' }
```

I currently loop through the collection and add the keys to an array and then sort the array and get last N document by those keys as following:

```
var ids = []
db.collection('events').get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      ids.push(doc.id)
    });
  })
  .then(()=>{
    //sortIds(ids);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ids[ids.length-2])) //second last entry 2019-01-07T08:21:28.614Z
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

This operation takes a long time if collection size increases. Is there an optimal way of achieving this (sorting/orderBy-descending collection and fetch last N documents)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation about this?  There's a whole page that describes sorting and limiting.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: I went through this but couldn't find a way to orderByKey. I could order by key in firebase realtime DB though using something like dbRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(n); Is there a way to order documents by key without adding the key into object?

Comment: It looks like you already have a timestamp field in the document.  Are you saying you can't use that?

Comment: ya that timestamp is thirdparty timestamp for some other purpose. The timestamp in the key is to make it unique entry based on timestamp when object was added to db. So are you suggesting that i need to keep this timestamp as well as part of the object?

Comment: Use FieldPath.documentId as the sort key.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#.documentId

Comment: Thanks will try this. But btw, even if i use db.collection('events').orderBy("timestamp", 'desc').limit(2).get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  })
This returns the objects in sorted order but the time taken is >10 secs for 100-200 documents much like what i do in my original code. I needed a sub 2-3 sec delay at max.

Comment: hi OP, have you found your answer? the answer suggested below `db.collection('events').orderBy("timestamp").limit(n)` works for me, it get N number of items, but this collection for me is live chat messages, and after pulling N items, i want to add more after new messages come in. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
db.collection('events').orderBy("timestamp").limit(n)
```

Comment: I had used this, but the time taken to return the n-entries is extremely high ~15 secs for a 100 document collection. I needed a way to get this data at sub 2 sec.

Comment: @AdityaMertia did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Doesnt work for me.